# how to recover HA clusters of Stacked control plane and etcd nodes

Tags: high-availability, etcd, stacked

I used kubeadm to setup a HA clusters (3 masters) of Stacked control plane and etcd nodes;But when I use kubeadm reset to destroy one master, cann't join a master to ha clusters anymore:

step1:

`docker run --rm -it --net host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.2.24 etcdctl --cert-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --key-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --ca-file /etcd/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --endpoints https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2379 member remove  xxxxxxx`

to remove the bad etcd;

step2:

```
docker run --rm -it --net host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.2.24 etcdctl --cert-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --key-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --ca-file /etcd/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --endpoints https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2379 cluster-health
……
……
cluster is healthy
```

step3:

```
kubeadm get cs
……
……
etcd-0      Healthy    {"health":"true"}
```

step4:

kubeadm join the new master to the ha cluster,but get wrong:

```
 etcd cluster is not healthy: context deadline exceeded
```

Any one can help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

$kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kubeadm-config
then remove the bad node information below apiEndpoints,
eg:  remove these three line of below
  master1-k8s:
    advertiseAddress: 172.16.12.216
    bindPort: 6443

finally you can use "kubeadm join" join the control-plane to HA clusters successfully!!!

Comment: You save my day. Thanks